# How to call javascript function from string with function body and send multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript

I try to call a function from string with body of the function. I know only parameter names and can pass parameters to function.

I tried [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/ao7rj97u/1/)

```
function callFunction(body, paramNames, params) {
  return new Function(paramNames, body)(params);
}
```

It only works for one parameter. How can I do it for several parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's `function callFunction(body, paramNames, ...params) {
  return new Function(paramNames, body)(...params);
}`, but whatever you are trying to do, stop.

Comment: Wow. I looked at your JSFiddle. I don't have an answer for you but how does this even work at all? Where is the logic? *mindblown*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want dynamically create functions, and pass parameters to it. Usually it done in two different steps: 1 - create the function, 2 - call it.

[Here is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/wkcL1ao2/2/)

```
function createFunction(body, paramNames) {
  return new Function(paramNames, body);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var func1 = createFunction("return a + 1;", ["a"]);
    var func2 = createFunction("return a + b;", ["a","b"]);
    $("#singleParam").text(func1.apply(this,[1]));
    $("#multipleParam").text(func2.apply(this, [1, 2]));
});
```